# How to execute a JavaScript function when returning HttpResponse?

Tags: javascript, python, django

Here's my scenario: User adds something to the shopping cart, and if the python view handling this logic does it successfully, it should fire off a JavaScript function saying 'You've added a product into your cart!'.

How would one go about doing that?

Here's what I tried so far:

```
return HttpResponse("alert('hello world');", mimetype="application/x-javascript")
```

but this just outputs the code as a string.

To be specific: I need to fire a function in a JS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In django 1.9 the following code works:

```
return HttpResponse("<script>alert('hello world');</script>")
```

Comment: This works, but I need to fire a specific function in a JS file. Any tips?

Comment: If your javascript file is included in the response you can just call the function in the script tags above. If i were you I would first write a html site that works, then copy the html and return it in the HttpResponse

Comment: If I add src tag, like this: http://pastebin.com/uKduU9L3, it suddenly stops working.

Comment: it seems you need some training in javascript. try it on an empty html page before trying it in django. tip: you need two script tags.

Comment: It seems like I've approchead my problem from the wrong perspective. I've accepted you're answer and sincerily thank you for the help.